# Clone an entire page to custom index.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a custom `index.php` file in my child theme overriding the default theme `index.php` file which loads first when the theme is first installed.

Is there a way to clone an entire page to `index.php` file by page name or id or slug? I will build a page by adding a new page from dashboard and add elements there. Now, when I build the page, I also want the `index.php` file look the same. Hope I make sense.

I have created a custom template as the `index.php` file. But not sure about the cloning process. Any help will be appreciative.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the code from *page.php* of your parent theme inside your *index.php* - in this file you'll have all that is needed to display a page.
For example in WP default theme, this code from *page.php* will display the current page using *content-page.php* template :

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
    endif;
endwhile;
```

Then, in WP settings, define your page as home page in Settings > Reading - it will tell wordpress to use that page for your *index.php* template.

Comment: Thanks I got it helps some how.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved this way.

```
<?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    $post_format = et_pb_post_format(); ?>
<?php
                    $page = get_page_by_title('Default Homepage'); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
echo $content;
?>
```